# What is the difference between using promises with and without return

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I was working with `Vuex` and had a problem that I could solve on my own. The problem was that action I created doesn't return data inside state with method `created` inside my Vue component. This problem got solved by simply adding `return` before new Promise.

So problem solved but I don't really understand the difference that made the problem get solved by using return. What does the difference having return makes?

This is my created function which before using return with actions didn't load data on initial loading

```
 created () {
        this.$store.dispatch('updateNews')
        .then( response => {
            this.news = this.$store.getters.getNews
        })
        .catch( error => this.error = "Error happened during fetching news" );
    },
```

This is my store after adding return

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    news: []
  },
  getters:{
    getNews(state){
      return state.news
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_NEWS(state, payload){
      state.news = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    updateNews(context){
      var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
      'country=us&' +
      'apiKey=something';
      return new Promise ( (res, rej) => {
        axios
          .get(url)
          .then(response => {
            context.commit('UPDATE_NEWS', response.data)
            res()
          })
          .catch( error => rej() )
      })
    }
  },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

a promise doesn't work as a simple declaration inside a function, you have actually return the promise to work with it. The case here is a little bit weird tho, becuase axios already returns a promise to work with. I think the problem is that you want to assing the value of a variable in the state of the store programatically to a variable in component data, when the correct flow for something like that would be accessing that value with a computed property, like this:

**Vuex**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    news: []
  },
  getters:{
    getNews(state){
      return state.news
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_NEWS(state, payload){
      state.news = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    updateNews(context){
      var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
      'country=us&' +
      'apiKey=something';
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then(response => {
          context.commit('UPDATE_NEWS', response.data)
        })
        .catch( error => console.log('Oops, something went wrong with the news', error) );
    }
  },

});
```

**Component**

```
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch('updateNews');
},
computed: {
  news() {
    return this.$store.getters.getNews;
  }
}
```

Using it like this, you don't have to make a variable called news inside component's data, just the computed property, and access it the same way you would access a variable returned in component's data